# Update time attribute in Rails, SUPER easy, i'm being dense

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, time

I have the following `RentalRequest` object:

```
#<RentalRequest id: 3, pickup_start: "2015-03-16 21:00:00", pickup_end: "2015-03-16 23:00:00">
```

I'd like to update `pickup_start` and `pickup_end` to be on 2015-03-17 instead. When I run:

```
RentalRequest.find(3).update_attribute(pickup_end: "2015-03-17 23:00:00")
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

Not sure what other argument I need to provide.

If it helps, here's the type and output of the attribute by itself

```
RentalRequest.find(3).pickup_end
=> Mon, 16 Mar 2015 23:00:00 UTC +00:00

RentalRequest.find(3).pickup_end.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look [at the docs for `update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attribute), see how it is expecting `name, value` as the arguments?

You're passing `name: value` which is a hash, a single argument of a hash. That's why you're getting the error about wrong number of arguments, the method is expecting 2 but you're providing only 1.

You can either change your code to call: `update_attribute( :pickup_end, "2015-03-etc..")` or you can use the `update_attributes` method instead, which takes a hash.  I'd recommend the latter, because then you can update both attributes at once, in the same SQL statement, and in the same DB transaction:

```
update_attributes pickup_end: "2015...etc", pickup_start: "2015...etc"
```

Comment: oh super weird... it looks like this has always been the case but part of the reason i asked this question is because i use update_attribute ALL THE TIME since it bypasses validation and have always used the name:value syntax and it has worked before...

Comment: @james the `update_attribute` signature has been the same since rails 1.0.0. You must be using `update_attributes` if you were passing a `Hash` argument. And if you need to set both i would use a before callback to handle setting `pickup_start` that way if you ever need to change this logic you only have to change it once.